# How can I set the default audio volume for Siri playing music on HomePod?

Tags: siri, apple-music, homepod

I like to ask Siri to play music, a playlist or a specific song. However, (s)he likes 50% volume and that's too loud for me. I looked at the settings and can't find how to set this:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208341

There are [articles on setting equalization when playing AirPlay](https://www.imore.com/how-adjust-eq-audio-levels-your-homepod), but I'm not using any device, just HomePod and voice command. For now, I have to say "Siri - set the volume to 25%" when I forget to do that. I do already [enable sound check](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-set-consistent-volume-on-homepod/), but that seems to be a 3 to 6% benefit and I’m looking to go from half volume to 1/4 or less.

Is there a way to make my preference more sticky and the music start more softly?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? - https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-set-consistent-volume-on-homepod/.

Comment: Thank you so much @slm - yes - I do have that, but it seems to be a small correction. I’ve edited my question - great suggestion and addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon some experimentation, the issue I’m having is that each device that connects to HomePod changes the “last volume” so if I forget to turn down my Mac volume when watching a video or show with low volume (or I’m playing some music at party volume) then the next time I ask Siri for the weather early in the morning, I will continue to be surprised by volume louder than I expected.

I’ve put in a feature request to reset the volume after 60 minutes to a low or pre-set level, but I’m not holding my breath Apple implements that or uses the microphones to realize the room has been silent as a mouse for an hour and adjust back the “system volume” to be an indoor voice in the morning after a night partying.

With iOS 15 and the sleep focus / synchronized alarms and sleep mode do not disturb, things seem a little better. Another workaround is to just ask Siri to play ambient sounds and set the volume low ensuring a mellow start to the day.

Comment: TLDR, I didn’t realize how volume worked. Operator error.